# how to insert the result of count into table

Tags: mysql-workbench

i have syntax like this

```
SELECT 
    b.buyer_id
FROM order_buyer b
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_buyer d
            WHERE d.buyer_id = b.buyer_id AND
                  d.createdAt >= '2018-10-01' AND d.createdAt < '2019-01-01') AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_buyer d
            WHERE d.buyer_id = b.buyer_id AND
                  d.createdAt >= '2018-10-01' AND d.createdAt < '2019-01-01' ) AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_buyer d
                WHERE d.buyer_id = b.buyer_id AND d.createdAt < '2018-10-01') group by buyer_id
```

how to make the result of this syntax which is the value of count, to insert to my new table

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO New_Table SELECT (then the rest of your statement)

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp